# Magento - error while media resources

Tags: css, magento, magento-1.8

We have modified an existing theme and introduced some new features.We now allows the admin to upload an image from admin panel and use it as a new logo. If admin uploads a new image the image gets stored in /magento/media directory ("magento" being the root dir). However I am not able to use this resource in my extension. I have a file I have a css file which defines css of the header section(with a default relative path to a standard logo) of every page. This css is referenced in head.phtml which actually displays the content. I am overriding the header section of the css by doing -

```
<style>
<?php

$img = Mage::getStoreConfig('mytheme/choosetheme/my_image');
$media = Mage::getBaseDir('media');

echo '.header-bg {
    background:url('.$media.'\logo.png'.') no-repeat center #fff;
    height:45px;

}';
</style>
```

And I get the following error - Not allowed to load local resource.

The image is uploaded from our extension and giving a relative path in css works fine but not a good solution because the pages can be any arbitrary path so the number of "../" to put is not fixed.

Please let me know how can I use an image from magento's media directory in my extension .phtml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't load images off a local file system.

Use

```
Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
```

instead of

```
Mage::getBaseDir('media');
```

Let me know if any issues

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked out. Also please let me know it there are any solid magento extension development guides, tutorials preferred. Thanks :)